# Setting dynamic environment for whenever scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron-task, whenever

I need to set the environment for my [whenever scheduler](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to all environment (`production`, `staging` & `development`)

I need this because I want the cron to trigger on any given environment.

I know I can set the environment as follow:

```
set :environment, 'staging'
```

or

```
set :environment, 'development'
```

etc

But any of these will only default the environment to the specified.

How can I set the environment to be all so as for it to work for all scenario?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you remove `set :environment` option. I think by default it considers current env.

Comment: No @Nithin It defaults the environment to `production`

Comment: does `Rails.env` work ?

Comment: No. :) that won't and doesn't work

Comment: I haven't set environment I have this in schedule.rb `env :PATH, ENV['PATH']` and scheduler job works fine for me.

Comment: oh, cool. that gives me an idea that I'll try out. but I don't know if it will work. will check

Answer (score 0):

While deploying you can set the environment like this in your deploy.rb file
`bundle exec whenever --update-crontab --set 'environment=#{rails_env}&path=#{deploy_to}/current/'`.